# Angular, actualizar valor desde javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

He estado trabajando en angular y hoy me surgido la necesidad de modificar un valor del scope desde una función javascript, sin embargo no he encontrado una manera eficiente de hacerlo desde afuera del controler, 
alguien sabe como podría hacerse?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Por favor, incluye un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas estar modificando una variable de manera global (diferentes controllers) deja de utilizar `$scope` ya que su alcance es en un solo controller. Te recomiendo que utilices `$rootScope` ya que el alcance de las variables declaradas aquí es mayor y puedes acceder a ellas desde cualquier controller.

Tendrás que inyectar en todos los controlles `$rootScope`.